# Magento 2: Multi-website redirects to main domain

Tags: magento2, redirect, multi-website

I have a multistore in Magento 2. The main website URL is `mainwebsite.ca`.

The second store runs through a subdirectory 'secondwebsite' and is accessed through the URL: `mainwebsite.ca/secondwebsite/`.

I want to redirect `mainwebsite.ca/secondwebsite/` to a new domain `abc.com`.

I have pointed the domain to the IP and updated the base URL from the Magento admin but when I visit `abc.com` it redirects to the `mainwebsite.ca`.

Am I missing something?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the `MAGE_RUN_CODE` and `MAGE_RUN_TYPE`?

If you are using Apache, refer this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/multi-site/ms_apache.html) to add MAGE_RUN_CODE and MAGE_RUN_TYPE.

If you are using Nginx, refer this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/multi-site/ms_nginx.html) to add MAGE_RUN_CODE and MAGE_RUN_TYPE.